# Why is $\sqrt{1 + \sin{x}}$ not differentiable?

Tags: calculus

$1 + \sin x$ has a very trivial graph and is differentiable

[image]

However as it is raised to some powers its graph changes
for example if x > 1 the graph has the following form
[image]

It has a broader base which seems understandable considering that when some $x < 1$ is raised to higher powers it will become even smaller

However I am not able to understand the graphs when it is raised to powers smaller than 1
[image]

In this case the graph suddenly becomes non differentiable, the reason for which I am not able to understand. Also mathematically how can I prove that $\sqrt{1 + \sin{x}}$ is non differentiable ?

Comment: There are kinks at $-\pi/2,3\pi/2$, etc. which make the function not differentiable at these points. Much like the canonical example of $f(x)=|x|$. To show non differentiability, compute the left and right hand derivative limits at these points and see that they're not equal.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to see that $f(x) = \sqrt{1+\sin x}$ is not differentiable at, say, $x = 3\pi/2$ would be to compute the derivative by the definition:
$$
f'(3\pi/2) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(3\pi/2 + h) - f(3\pi/2)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1 + \sin(3\pi/2 + h)}}{h}.
$$
This limit is a bit tricky.  Hint:  Try computing
$$
\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{1+\sin(3\pi/2+h)}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \sqrt{\frac{1+\sin(3\pi/2+h)}{h^2}}
$$
and then do a similar calculation for the limit as $h \to 0^-$.

Answer (score 0):

At $x=0$, $$x^\alpha$$ is differentiable for $\alpha\ge1$ and not differentiable for $\alpha<1$, as you can check by computing the derivative.

Now close to its minima, $\sqrt{1+\sin x}$ behaves like a (rectified) linear function.

Comment: I think the final sentence could use more explanation.  One way to explain it would be to use the Taylor series for $\sin x$ centered at $3\pi/2$:  $\sin x = -1 + (x-3\pi/2)^2/2 - (x-3\pi/2)^4/4!+ \cdots$ and therefore $\sqrt{1+\sin x} = \sqrt{(x-3\pi/2)^2/2 - (x-3\pi/2)^4/4! + \cdots} = |x-3\pi/2|\sqrt{1/2 - (x-3\pi/2)^2/4! + \cdots}$.  For $x$ close to $3\pi/2$, $\sqrt{1+\sin x} \approx |x-3\pi/2| \sqrt{1/2}$.